# Ubuntu mounting partition read only error

Tags: partitioning, mount

So I have a SD card in read only mode I have put 2 partitions on it the first partition contains ubuntu with boot flags the second partition contains some files

I can boot into ubuntu with the SD card but when I try to mount the second partition it says 'error /dev/sda1 in read only mode' I have tried setting the read only flags on mount but it still is not working.

Can you access different partitions on an active disk i am not sure why this is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- boot into Ubuntu
- open the `terminal`
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- note the name of your second partition (ie:/dev/sda2, /dev/sdb2, etc.)
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda1` # change sda1 if need be
- type your mount command for the second partition, or just reboot

---

**Note**: If /dev/sda1 is, in fact, your boot partition, you'll have to do it this way...

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX` # replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: thanks this worked i understand it was because the partition was not correctly dismounted